# Performance issues with windows server, sql-server and apache

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, sql-server, django, sql-server-2008-r2

I am running into some performance issues on my server, which runs Windows server 2008, SQL Server 2008 R2, and apache.  This is a purely internal website, and is accessed by a total of about 6 people.  However, those six use it heavily all day.  My issue is that django frequently reports a MSSQL timeout error.  The problem arises when there are several users, each with a few pages loading.  AFAICS, there are a few things which could be causing this:

1. My django configuration: I am using Johnny Cache, with a memcached backend.  For reference, django-debug-toolbar (which only runs on my testing environment, not the server) shows that an average page results in about 100 SQL queries.  Is this normal?  However, I also have a couple of pages which pull data for multiple records, and can go up to 2000 SQL queries
2. Apache/MSSQL configuration: I don't know much about tuning either of these so I have left them both with default settings.  Is there anything specific I should do to improve performance?
3. Insufficient resources.  My server (which is a VM) appears to be running fine, using about 20% CPU and about 60% RAM.  It has two Intel Xenon dual-core processors and 4GB RAM.

To summarise my question, can anyone with a bit of experience in this sort of setup give me any advice on which of the above I should focus on to improve performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rule out server related performance issue it might be worth monitoring the number of Hard Faults/sec under resource monitor. A high number of page fault or any increase means you are trying to access data that is on the hard drive rather than in memory.

I also found out that the percentages that windows 2008 reports on a VM can be unreliable at times. Make sure that the amount of memory that you have allocated for your VM matches the value that windows is reporting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Hard Faults/sec sits at 0, so that seems ok.  Any other suggestions?